Excel Formula changes values after a day or so
I have a bunch of text strings separated by commas in a cell (e.g., in COLUMN A here).



Column A
Column B




AA,AB,AC
??


AC,AZ,BB
??


AB,BB,CD
??



Each one of these texts is associated with values in a separate sheet called LEGEND.



Column A
Column B




AA
15


AB
20


AC
35


BA
90



I want the sum of the values (in Column B on first sheet) associated with the text strings.
I have this Vlookup formula in my excel sheet at column B on first sheet
=SUM(VLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,","),LEGEND!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)).
It gives me the correct SUM but the issue is that when I re-open my file after a day, it only returns the first value and NOT the SUM. e.g., when I run the formula first time, it gives me 70 for the first one but after a day when I re-open my file, the value is already replaced with 15.
Please help.
I have tried Mutiple formulas to fix this, but it didn't help.

Well, did this and saved, closed & reopened and still gives results:
SUM(SUMIFS(B$9:B$12,A$9:A$12,TEXTSPLIT(A2,,",")))

Just to prove the points I made in the comment, see:


Thank you for the answer but I have both the tables on different sheets which is why I used VLOOKUP. I will try this formula and see if it will work for my spreadsheet. Thanks again.

@Anonymous so specify the ranges on the other sheets, or name the ranges and use the names.
